# xgboost regression predict same value

Tags: python, regression, xgboost

I am new to machine learning and `xgboost`and I am solving a regression problem.
My target value are very small (e.g.-1.23e-12).

I am using linear regression and `xgboost` regressor, 
but `xgboost` always predicts the same values, like:

```
[1.32620335e-05 1.32620335e-05 ... 1.32620335e-05].
```

I tried to tune some parameters in xgboost.regressor, but it also predicted the same values.

I've seen [Scaling of target causes Scikit-learn SVM regression to break down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593640/scaling-of-target-causes-scikit-learn-svm-regression-to-break-down)
, so I tried to scale  my target value to likes(data.target = data.target*(10**12))
, and it fixed the problem. But I am not sure this is reasonable to scale my target value, and I don't know if this problem in xgboost is the same to SVR?
.

Here is target value of my data:

```
    count    2.800010e+05
    mean    -1.722068e-12
    std      6.219815e-13
    min     -4.970697e-12
    25%     -1.965893e-12
    50%     -1.490800e-12
    75%     -1.269998e-12
    max     -1.111604e-12
```

And part of my code:

```
    X = df[feature].values
    y = df[target].values *(10**(12))
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
    xgb = xgboost.XGBRegressor()
    LR = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    xgb.fit(X_train,y_train)
    LR.fit(X_train,y_train)
    xgb_predicted = xgb.predict(X_test)
    LR_predicted = LR.predict(X_test)
    print('xgb predicted:',xgb_predicted[0:5])
    print('LR predicted:',LR_predicted[0:5])
    print('ground truth:',y_test[0:5])
```

Output:

```
    xgb predicted: [-1.5407631 -1.49756   -1.9647646 -2.7702322 -2.5296502]
    LR predicted: [-1.60908805 -1.51145989 -1.71565321 -2.25043287 -1.65725868]
    ground truth: [-1.6572993  -1.59879922 -2.39709641 -2.26119817 -2.01300088]
```

And the output with `y = df[target].values` (i.e., did not scale target value)

```
    xgb predicted: [1.32620335e-05 1.32620335e-05 1.32620335e-05 1.32620335e-05
     1.32620335e-05]
    LR predicted: [-1.60908805e-12 -1.51145989e-12 -1.71565321e-12 -2.25043287e-12
     -1.65725868e-12]
    ground truth: [-1.65729930e-12 -1.59879922e-12 -2.39709641e-12 -2.26119817e-12
     -2.01300088e-12]
```

Comment: You are probably hitting precision issues (since values are so small). Scaling is okay for linear regression.You are just solving 1e12*(ax+b) instead of ax+b. Is that your question?

Comment: hi dumgo, yes, but even if I didn't scale target with 1e12*(ax+b) , the linear regression can predict more reasonable value than xgboost.

Comment: Can you share some details of your data and code?

Comment: OK, I just update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try something simpler. I suspect that if you tried to fit a DecisionTreeRegressor (sklearn) to your problem (without scaling) you will likely see similar behavior.

Also, most likely, the nodes in your (xgboost) trees are not getting split at all, see by doing `xgb.get_booster().get_dump()`

Now, try this: run multiple experiments, scale your y such that each y is of the order 1e-1, then next experiment scale such that order of y is 1e-2, so on. You will see that decision tree stops splitting around some order. I believe it is linked to minimum impurity value, for example, sklearn decision tree value is here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ed5e127b/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L285 (around 1e-7)

This is my best guess at the moment. If someone can add to or verify this then I'll be happy to learn :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried experiment you advised and the output is performed as you said. I will try more experiment on this problem later

Comment: Sure, please post if you find something different. Thanks.